# Pan div contents on mousemove jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, so this is what I have:

```
<div id="imageWrapper">
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="250px" height="180px" />
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="250px" height="180px" />
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="250px" height="180px" />
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="250px" height="180px" />
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="250px" height="180px" />
   ...
</div>
```

The imageWrapper div has a set width/height and overflow:hidden via CSS, then a lot of image thumbnails inside that together, are larger than the parent div.

What I'm trying to achieve is when your mouse is inside the imageWrapper div and you move your mouse the thumbs scroll horizontal/vertical dependent on position in order to be able to scroll around and see all the thumbs?

I've tried numerous jQuery plugins but they all seem to be geared towards panning a single large image rather than the contents of a div.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I have quickly put this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uN8D/6/) demo together. I will tidy it up when I have more time later but it should give you a start.

The basics of it is to get the full width & height of the images by copying them into another div out of the viewport. Once calculated I can work out a percentage that should be scrolled when the mouse moves over the wrapping div.

Comment: @Scott - well you changed the dimensions of the images in the wrapper but when they are copied the images do not have those same dimensions - so the math is wrong!

Comment: @Scott - well yeah what do you expect! You added a float to each image, so now they wrap inside the container. There can be no x scroll now....

Comment: Even without the float there is no x scroll

Comment: Scott, they dont need to scroll, you have a 1000px container....there is no scroll x.....they wrap around still

Comment: @scott - what you after is a container set to say 400px, then an inner container where all the images wrap around....this will require other calcs but you did not describe this really in your q.

Comment: I probably could have explained it a little better. Basically, I have viewport > #imageWrapper, imageWrapper is going to be set to like 2000 x 2000px so obviously there will be x and y scrollbars to view entire thumb content, I want to hide the scrollbars and have the mouse movement do the scrolling. Make sense? Cheers!

Comment: You should be able to apply my code to take care of this. All the ideas needed are in my sample.

Comment: Thanks for your help @redsquare. In the end I modified this script: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-image-panning as it already has easing built in too.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the imageWrapper div, make imageWrapper the size it should be to contain all the pictures inside, and the biggerWrapper make overflow hidden, that way you could pan the inner div as a single element. (negative margins would probably be used)

Comment: That's the problem, every plugin I've found has been for panning images only not div's...